# Proof that a Lipschitz function is a.e. approximately differentiable by using it is "almost" $C^1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, geometric-measure-theory

I am trying to do the following exercise: to prove that a Lipshitz function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^m$ is $\mathcal{L}^n$-almost everywhere approximately differentiable using the following fact:

"For every $\epsilon$ there exists a function $g \in C^1$ such that $\mathcal{L}^ n (\{ g \neq f \} ) < \epsilon$."

I know about Rademacher theorem, but of course I cannot use it here, it is just an exercise as I said.

Now, a function $f$ is said to be approximately differentiable at a point $x_0$ if there exists a linear functional $L$ (depending on $x_0$) such that the set $\left \lbrace x \text{ s.t. } \frac{|f(x) - f(x_0) - L (x-x_0)|}{|x-x_0| } < \delta \right \rbrace$ has density 1 in $x_0$ for every $\delta>0$.

A set $A$ having density 1 in $x_0$ means

$$ \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\mathcal{L}^n (B(x_0,r) \cap A)}{\omega_n r^n} =1.$$

Consider the set $A = \cap_m \{ g_m = f\}$ where $g_m \in C^1$ such that $\mathcal{L}^ n (\{ g_m \neq f \} ) < \epsilon/2^m$ for some $\epsilon >0$. Now, the set $A$ has density 1 in almost every point $x_0 \in A$, i.e. :

$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\mathcal{L}^n (B_r (x_0) \cap A)}{\omega_n r^n} =1. $$

This follows simply by noticing that almost every point of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Lebesgue point for $\mathcal{I}_A$, the characteristic function of $A$.

Then if we call $L$ the Lipschitz constant of $f$ one has:

$$L \geq \lim_{x_n \to x_0}\frac{|f(x_0) - f(x_n)|}{|x_0 -x_n|} = \lim_{x_n \to x_0}\frac{|g_m(x_0) - g_m(x_n)|}{|x_0 -x_n|} =|\nabla g_m |(x_0)$$

for every $m$ and for every $n$. To make things easier, assume $x_0 = 0 \in A$, $f(0)=0$ and denote $L_m := \nabla g_m (0)$. Eventually considering a subsequence, there exists $\tilde {L}$ limit of the $L_m$ (in the operator sense), and chooising $L= \tilde{L}$ in the definition of the approximate differentiability condition gives that:

$$ \frac{|f(x)- \tilde{L}x|}{|x|} \leq \frac{|f(x) - g_m (x)|}{|x|} +  \frac{|g_m(x) - L_m (x)|}{|x|} +  \frac{|L_m(x) - \tilde{L} (x)|}{|x|}$$

But for $x$ a Lebesgue point of $A$ the first term is 0 in a set of density 1, while the second and the third can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $|x|$ sufficiently small and $m$ sufficiently big, respectively. Then $f$ is approximately differentiable at every $x_0 \in A$. But $\mathcal{L}^n (A^c) \leq \epsilon$ and I can conclude by sending $\epsilon$ to 0. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems.

1. I can't understand your idea. Why you are considering $A = \bigcap\limits_{m=1}^\infty \{ f= g_m\}$? And, also, you've found a limit $\bar L$ of $L_m$. The set $A$ here is a set where $f$ equals to **every** $C^1$ function $g_k$, but $g_k$ is an $C^1$-extension of $f$, that's why I can't understand attempt to find limit of $L_m$.
2. $\mathcal L^n(A) \le \varepsilon$. How you have got it? I think it's an errata and you have $\mathcal L^n(\mathbb R^n \setminus A) \le \varepsilon$.

*Possible solution.*
Better consider next situation. Let $A_k$ be a measurable set such that there exists a $C^1$ function $g_k\colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ with the following property
$$
f(x) = g_k(x) \quad\text{for all $x\in A_k$,} \quad \mathcal L^n(\mathbb R^n\setminus A_k) \le 2^{-k}.
$$
Then you have decomposition $\mathbb R^n = \Sigma \cup \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ where $\mathcal L^n(\Sigma) = 0$ and $\left. f \right|_{A_k}$ is a "trace" of $C^1$ function. Also we can assume that $A_k$ are disjoint, because we can consider sets $B_k = A_k \setminus\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}A_i$. Hence, $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty A_k= \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty B_k$ and $\left. f\right|_{B_k} =g_k$. If $x \in B_k$ then $\left. f\right|_{B_k}$ is approximately differentiable at the $x$. But if $x \in B_k$ then $x$ is a point of density $0$ for the set $\mathbb R^n \setminus B_k$.

And about your solution. Your solution is almost correct. When you define a set $A = \bigcap\limits_m \{g_m = f\}$ you get a some set and a **only one function** $g$ such that $g_m = g$. Finding a limit of the subsequence $\nabla g_m$ is not a big deal, because this limit equals to $\nabla g$ (and, of course, equals to any $\nabla g_m$).
So if $x\in \mathbb R^n$ you can vary $\varepsilon>0$ and find a $\varepsilon_0$ such that there exists $A$, $\mathcal L^n(\mathbb R^n\setminus A) \le \varepsilon_0$ and other properties, but also we obtain that $x\in A$ (this is true for almost all $x \in \mathbb R^n$).

Comment: For 2): Yes it's an errata. As for 1) (and the hint), at the moment I don't remember why I thought I had to choose a sequence of $g_m$. I can't see why you cannot simply choose a $g$ which coincides with $f$ in a set whose complement has measure $\leq \epsilon$.

Comment: @tommy1996q, you are right! I hurried with some details in my answer. Idea here to pick a disjoint partition of the space, where our function is continuously differentiable. I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: Riiiight! I'll edit my answer when I have some time, thanks!